# Enemy AI in game is eating too much RAM

Tags: c#, performance, memory, optimization, ram

I need help. I'm currently trying to make a game and so far I'm doing okay. The only major problem I've encountered is adding enemy AI. Without the AI, my game only uses about 200-400mb of ram. When I made the AI, the game now eats upwards of 2GB of RAM. That's too much for a simple 2D Game. Here's a sample of the AI code(please assume that all necessary syntax is in my program. There are no errors since I can get it to run):

```
public void launch()
 {
enemyGen.Tick += enemyGen_Tick;// in charge of generating enemies
        enemyGen.Interval = 1000;
        enemyGen.Start();
 }
 private void eneMove_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            if (eneGen[a] == 1)//creates BLUE ENEMY
            {

                EnAIaY[a] += 2;
                eneCount++;
                if (a == 3)
                { a = 0; }
            }
        }
    }

 private void enemyGen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (eneCount < 3)//creates an enemy if there are less than 3 enemies
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
            {
                if (eneGen[a] != 1)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    eneGen[a] = rnd.Next(0, 5);//Generates a random number for enemy generation
                    if (a == 3)
                    { a = 0; }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

To explain the code I made, there is an array of 3 objects. In "enemygen_Tick", I had it generate a random number between 0 and 5 per array object. Every time the number generated was a 1, it would spawn an enemy.

I also added an if statement in the for loops so that every time the for loop would reach 3, the maximum number of objects, it would start generating random numbers again per object.

My question is how do I reduce RAM usage? When the program reaches the 2GB memory usage point, it starts lagging so bad.

There is a null reference exception after the first enemy despawns(gets eliminated), but that's a question for another time. I can't debug the game if a Powerpoint slide has a faster FPS than the game.

Comment: Is this a x86 or an x64 application? (If AnyCPU what is the launching application's bitness)

Comment: one problem spotted. dont declare `Random rnd` in loop

Comment: But how am I going to generate enemies randomly without Random ints?

Comment: At first glance, your code goes against a principle known as "Single Responsibility", a pedantic term that means that each of your methods should be responsible for doing "one thing, and one thing only".

While not directly being responsible for performance problems, if you begin to code this way, it does help avoid code that creates performance problems.  

As a commenter already noted, generating a random number inside a loop this nested is usually a bad idea especially as you're instantiating a Random object, and for games that's an expensive operation.

Comment: May you kindly explain? I'm not familiar with those principles. This game is for a an Object Oriented Programming class I'm taking and it's also the first time I've had to make a game using C#.

Comment: you must declare `Random rnd` outside loop otherwise you will get mostlikely same numbers

Comment: Well for example, you have a method called enemyGen_Tick.   Inside which you make a comment that "//Generates a random number for powerup generation".   Now to me, enemyGen and powerup generation are two different things.  This may make sense in your head, but to me it indicates something is wrong with how you've approached this problem.

Whenever I get into a situation like this, I'll add a break-point, and debug every single line to see if the program flow is going how I expect it to.

Comment: Hmm... but here's the thing. I need to have 3 separate, random numbers generated to determine the spawning of 3 enemies. If I shouldn't put Random in a loop, should I then declare a random number per array object?

Comment: IanL I'm sorry. The syntax for the random number generation was  copy pasted from another method for powerup generation. it uses the same algorithm, but what I posted above is really only for enemy generation. I'll go edit the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You could move Random rnd = new Random(); to the very start of the method before the loops, as a quick fix.  It may not fix the main problem, but instantiating things at the beginnning of a method is a good rule of thumb.  

But for larger game design projects, you may want to manage your random numbers outside of individual methods (going back to Single Responsibility), so you can take advantage of things like random number seeds for procedural generation etc, but that's another matter.

Comment: Going back to the main question, if you think the code you've posted is responsible for the 2GB of memory - the number 1 probable cause is that this code is running more often than it should be (are you sure it's taking interval into account), and/or that's it's doing expensive things that would cause the heap to expand - and the number one cause of that is lines of code that use the `new` keyword.

Also, code that checks if an enemy needs to spawn probably doesn't need to happen every frame.

Comment: To amplify what's already been said: the entire game should have one and only one instance of Random, created during startup initialization.

Comment: To mention another point: Why are you using an array for you enemys? A list made out of something like `EnemyClass` would make much more sense and prevents many many problems because of simplicity. You wouldn't need to have decoupled stuff like `eneCount` and `eneGen`, that's really hard to keep synchronized.

Comment: To clarify what's already been said: `Random rnd = new Random(); ` does *not* generate a random number, it merely creates an object of type `Random` It's the `rnd.Next(..)` that returns the random numbers, so *it* goes in the loop, but the creation of the Random object should only be done once..  That said, it's probably not what's causing you to use 2GB.

Comment: On the other hand, you should confirm *how often* you Tick event handlers are being called, because if they were being called say a million times a second, instead of once a second (which you probably intend), then your memory could be filling up with Random objects and others before the garbage collector had a chance to release them.  Also, the CPU overhead could make the game run extremely slowly.

Comment: I'm not sure here but I don't think `eneCount` variable will ever have a value of 3

Comment: The code you show does not cause memory usage to increase.

Comment: So I put the Random rnd = new Random(); outside of the enemyGen_Tick; method. I placed it in the class FormDesign and now the game eats less RAM, but the RAM usage still gets to 2GB if I leave the game on long enough.

Comment: did you check to see how often your Tick event handlers are being called per second as suggested?

Comment: Isn't it that a tick of 1000 interval means 1 second? I did increase the interval and my RAM usage got cut in half, but my game is still laggy and 1GB of memory is too much for a 2D game.